# Continuity of first partial derivates of $u(x, y) = \arctan(\sqrt{x^4 + y^2})$ at $(0, 0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Given $u(x, y) = \arctan(\sqrt{x^4 + y^2})$ I have to find, whether its partial derivatives are continuous at $(0, 0)$. Using double limit, we get that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{1+x^4 + y^2}\frac{2x^3}{\sqrt{x^4 + y^2}} = 0 = \lim_{y \to 0} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1+x^4 + y^2}\frac{2x^3}{\sqrt{x^4 + y^2}}.$$
And so for partial derivative at $x$ it holds that
\begin{equation}
\partial_x u(x, y) =  \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{1+x^4 + y^2}\frac{2x^3}{\sqrt{x^4 + y^2}} & (x, y) \neq (0,0) \\
      0 & (x, y) = (0, 0) 
   \end{cases}.
\end{equation}
To prove that I can find the upper bound as follows
$$\left|\frac{1}{1+x^4 + y^2}\frac{2x^3}{\sqrt{x^4 + y^2}}\right| \leq 1\left|\frac{2x^3}{\sqrt{x^4 + y^2}}\right| \leq 2|x| = 2||x, 0||_1.$$

First question that rises here, is about my third bound. Is it legal to discard $y$ in fraction? Is it legal to show that $2|x| = 2||x, 0||_1$ and hence the continuity follows? (In our exams, we **must** find final upper bounds via norm.)

For partial derivative at $y$ we can show that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{1+x^4 + y^2}\frac{2x^3}{\sqrt{x^4 + y^2}} = 0 \neq \lim_{y \to 0} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1+x^4 + y^2}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^4 + y^2}} = 1.$$
And so partial derivative is discontinuous at $(0, 0)$.

Is my approach correct?